# Ms dynamics crm 2013 subgrid overlap with its add button

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

In Ms dynamics crm 2013 when we hide and show a subgrid using JavaScript visible function then subgrid's add button overlap with subgrid. Is there any way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the schema name of the sub grid.  You can do this by opening the form editor and then double clicking on the specific sub-grid.  [image: Here's an example]

To hide the sub-grid, you want to make sure to use supported JavaScript. To hide:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('ProjectRisks').setVisible(false);
```

To show:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('ProjectRisks').setVisible(false);
```

When testing, these worked fine for me.